# Java Agent not receiving updates after launching

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus-formula, lotus-designer

I am calling a Java agent using Formula code:

```
@Command([RunAgent]; "My Agent");
```

The agent runs and reads its parameters correctly. Some documents might change while the agent is still running. The agent doesn't see the changes and keeps reading the old values. To be concrete, the processing might be cancelled, so I am trying to tell my agent to stop.  I am doing this by changing the value in a document I dedicated for passing arguments to the agent:

```
Call doc.ReplaceItemValue("Pause","True")
Call doc.Save(True, False)
```

This is what the agent does:

```
 Session session = getSession();
 AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();
 Database db = agentContext.getCurrentDatabase();
'Reload the document with the parameters
 paramDoc = db.getDocumentByID(paramDoc.getNoteID());
```

But the agent only sees the default values. It seems to have an image of the database as it was at the time of calling it.

Any clue as to how to inform the agent about the new values or pausing/cancelling its thread?

Comment: There seems to be no solution. I had to use environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

In order to read the current value (discard cache) use:

```
noteid = paramDoc.getNoteID()
Delete paramDoc
paramDoc = db.getDocumentByID(noteid);
```

well, this was for LotusScript - you are using Java in agent. So I guess it will be (edited to include clarification as proposed by nempoBu4):

```
String noteid = paramDoc.getNoteID();
paramDoc.recycle();
paramDoc = db.getDocumentByID(noteid);
//Check the new value
```

Comment: But this removes the document entirely from the database!

Comment: @AHH This will not remove the document from the database. `paramDoc.recycle()` remove the document only from `Database` object cache.

Comment: I tried this and reloaded the object again, but I am getting the NotesException "Object has been removed or recycled"!

Comment: I added more code to make it clear how it is meant to be used

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Refresh method of the NotesDocument class. You need to call that before you check the value in your agent, to get any updated values.

Comment: This is the first thing I tried. NotesDocument doesn't have such a method. Maybe you mean NotesUIDocument

Comment: You are correct. In that case, the only way I can think about to do what you want is to reopen the document every time you want/need to check if the value has changed. Normunds' answer is a good example of that. You could also use the DocumentID instead of NoteID if you like.